# xml drawable does not works properly on Lollipop API21

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

**EDITED**

Decided to delete all of the previous question, since I made a standalone app just for solving this issue.

**Problem:** xml drawable does not works properly on API21, when defined as a background of a Button. and works on all other API's. Including API22 which is still Lollipop. really strange..

After making this standalone app, I realize that it might really be an API21 bug related to xml gradients. So in this app I put just a button on it in which I set the background to a drawable xml selector that changes the background drawable file depending on the state of the Button.

From what I could understand was that **on API21 it only uses the start color of the gradient.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   >

   <Button
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:background="@drawable/key_pressed_selector"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**background_key_default.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
          android:startColor="@color/grey"
          android:endColor="@color/grey"
    />
<corners android:radius="15dp"/>
```

**background_yellow.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:type="radial"
          android:gradientRadius="100"
          android:startColor="@color/dark_blue"
          android:endColor="@color/yellow"
    />
<corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

**background_pressed_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_yellow"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_key_default"/>

</selector>
```

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow">#ffff39</color>
    <color name="dark_blue">#332ff2</color>
    <color name="grey">#b1b2b6</color>   
</resources>
```

[image: app running on API19]
[image: app running on API21]

Comment: your background_selector is missing tag of <selector, if its typo or missed it please update n check... I have checked everything, it should work there is no bug which you mentioned. check your colors or styles for above api v-21

Comment: Thank you for your observation, because actually I competently forgot about the values-v21, so it was basically empty. I had just tried to copy and past the values that I have to the values-v21, but still have the same problem. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Shishram, I had completely reformulated the question with a standalone test, could you just have a look at it again please?

Comment: I will check and let you know. @Andre Gomes

Comment: @Shishram, it's solved now, thank you anyway!

Comment: alright!, you can post your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to override onTouch() method

simply try giving your selector xml file to the button's background.

**EXAMPLE**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/id_Login_login_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your_selector_xmlfile"
    android:text="Login" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I do need to override onTouch() because I need to know if the user pressed any of the keys to play a given sound. and them when I Override OnTouch() it does not set the pressed state to my ImageButtons.

Comment: yeah, but if you want to get the button pressed event onClick() would be good instead of onTouch() 

try adding onclickListners to your buttons 

since you have so many buttons in one activity you better make your activity implements OnClickListner to observe whick button clicked
for example [Refer here](https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! To me there is a bug with this xml attribute [android:gradientRadius](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:gradientRadius) on version API21.

The way I solved this was to create a drawable-v21 folder and copy all of my xml drawable that have this xml attribute and use one of this appendix: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

While leaving the default drawable folder without appendix.

otherwise I was not able to make it work, when it worked on API21 it didn't on all others API's and when it worked on all others API's it didn't on API21.

To me it worked like this.

ex:

**drawable**

```
android:gradientRadius="110"
```

**drawable-v21**

```
android:gradientRadius="55%p"
```